# Cycle through assigned colors on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have a mouseover (hover) state I’m trying to work out. I have a set of anchors, and I’m wrapping each letter in a span and assigning a color to each from an array. What I’m looking to do is on mouseover, assign a color to each span again repeatedly in a sequence (from the array), like a constantly animating color sequence across each letter of a word.

Updated: Currently the current anchor cycles (with help from Andrew Shearer I ended up targeting the current instead of all anchors), but not each individual cycling to its next color ... it’s working but a bit weird.

[A simple visual of what I’m trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyGiQ.gif)

My start below:

```
var colors = [
    "red",
    "lightsalmon",
    "violet",
    "skyblue"];

  $('a').each(function (index) {
    var characters = $(this).text().split("");

    $this = $(this);
    $this.empty();
    $.each(characters, function (i, el) {
      $this.append(`<span style="color: ${colors[i % colors.length]}">${el}</span>`);
    });

  });

  $('a').on('mouseover', function () {
    var span = $(this).find('span');

    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
      color = colors.shift();
      span.each(function (i) {
        $(this).next().attr("style", `color:${colors[i % colors.length]}`);
      });
      colors.push(color);
    }, 500);
  }).on('mouseleave', function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34bj70tn/

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g4aq35xr/)? Based on @Andrew answer

Comment: @SUTerliakov that’s super close :-) I think I can get there from here! 

Answer (score 1):

**A CSS Solution**

The rainbow marquee can be created using only css:

- Wrap each character in a span element
- Add some [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to configure the marquee
- Add a [key frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) animation for colour sequence
- Apply the animation to each span using [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

**Details**

We can avoid having to create multiple animations by adding a negative [timing delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) to each character. This causes the animation to start immediately but at a forward frame. And this way each character stars with different colour.

The animations use [step-end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) timing. This causes the animation to make sharp (rather than gradual) colour transitions like a physical marquee.

The snippet uses a bit of JavaScript on page load to wrap the text characters in spans. However, if you were to add the spans in the markup then no JavaScript is required.

**Snippet**

```js
// This is called once at to wrap each character in a span to be animated.
// Alternatively, you could add the spans in the markup

document.querySelectorAll('.rainbow')
  .forEach(element => {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerText
      .split('')
      .map(char => `<span>${char}</span>`)
      .join('');
});
```

```css
/* Set colors and timing via root variables */

:root {
  --rainbow-color-1: red;
  --rainbow-color-2: lightsalmon;
  --rainbow-color-3: violet;
  --rainbow-color-4: skyblue;
  --rainbow-speed: 1;
}

.rainbow span {
  animation: calc(var(--rainbow-speed) * 1s) step-end reverse infinite;
}

.rainbow span:nth-child(4n+1) {
  animation-name: rainbow-animation;
}

.rainbow span:nth-child(4n+2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--rainbow-speed) * -0.25s);
  animation-name: rainbow-animation;
}

.rainbow span:nth-child(4n+3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--rainbow-speed) * -0.5s);
  animation-name: rainbow-animation;
}

.rainbow span:nth-child(4n+4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--rainbow-speed) * -0.75s);
  animation-name: rainbow-animation;
}

@keyframes rainbow-animation {
  0% {
    color: var(--rainbow-color-1);
  }
  25% {
    color: var(--rainbow-color-2);
  }
  50% {
    color: var(--rainbow-color-3);
  }
  75% {
    color: var(--rainbow-color-4);
  }
}




/* for demo page only */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.card {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card rainbow">Stack Overflow!</div>

<div class="card rainbow">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Hey @yogi neat! I didn’t think of a css solution just because adding the spans has to be dynamic. This is a cool solution, thanks :-)